# RDS Database connection failed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployed app

Tags: c#, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a .NET 7 console application, developed using c# 11. Data are stored inside an AWS RDS Database (SQL Server) and connection is successfully established when running the application from inside Visual Studio 2022.

Once deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment (via AWS Toolkit extension in Visual Studio) the application starts, but no connection can be established. I get the following error:

> ***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)***

Now, as I already said, running the application in Visual Studio works fine, so I suppose the connection string is valid and correct.

I'm almost certain the problem is related to RDS security group inbound rules. To make the connection work from Visual Studio I added my public IP to the security group of RDS Database and it worked. But I cannot guess the correct setting to do the same thing for the deployed application. I already tried to use EC2 public IP, but it doesn't seem to be the right way.

Can please somebody lead me to the right direction ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It also seems to me that it is related with your RDS security group inbound rules. Like it worked by adding for your machine's IP address where your VS is there. Similarly, you need to add security group id with the port 1433 of Elastic Beanstalk instances into same inbound rule to allow the traffic.